# Use functions from hashlib in a Python numba function

Tags: python, numba, hashlib

How to use functions from `hashlib`, e.g. `sha256` inside a `@jit()` or `@jit(nopython=True)` Numba decorated-function?

Example:

```
import hashlib
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def main():
    for i in range(10000):  # the goal of using Numba is to speed up massively this loop, and it works
        b = b'1234'         # except for the sha256 part
        h = hashlib.sha256(b).digest()
        # many other things using i in my real code, but the only important thing for this question is sha256

main()
```

I get this error:

> numba.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
>   Unknown attribute 'sha256' of type Module()

Without `nopython=True`, I have a similar error.

Comment: Take a look at code snippets on this article: https://perso.crans.org/besson/publis/notebooks/Benchmark_of_the_SHA256_hash_function__Python_Cython_Numba.html#The-SHA2_Numba-class
It seems that you should create a wrapper class for the `Hash` object and then add `@jit` decorators to that wrapper.

Comment: Looks like there is no support for `hashlib` module: http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html#standard-library-modules

Comment: It is not possible to use arbitrary Python packages. You can implement it completely in Numba or you can wrap a C-Implementation. Wrapping a C-Implementation is quite often simpler, than implementing it from scratch. Do you know a simple C-Implementation which does what you want?